# Does ios cache data saved using NSKeyedArchiver internal?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nskeyedarchiver

I have found that if I delete the file saved by `NSKeyedArchiver`, I can still get the data using `NSKeyedUnarchiver`.

Comment: No, but if you load the data into memory first, then delete the file, you can still decode the data because it's already in memory. If you show your code we can confirm/give an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

[`NSKeyedArchiver`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nskeyedarchiver) & `NSKeyedUnarchiver` only encode and decode your objects so they can be stored and retreived.

The encoded data can be stored in Filemanager/Database/`NSUserDefaults` then you need to delete the data as appropriate for the store.